# Excel does not recognise my xll file

Tags: c, excel, mingw, codeblocks, xll

I created my first xll file with codeblocks & mingw, following this guide 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474/en-us

The problem is that the dll file, renamed as xll file, is not recognised by excel.

I do not understand the meaning of point 10 of the guide i linked, thus that might be my problem. I thought that def files were an output of the compiler. Why is the guide suggesting that they are an input?

If they are an input, how can I set codeblocks to take the def file as an input?

Thank you.

[EDIT] Issue solved:
In case someone incur in the same problem, the issue was definitely the naming convention of the exported functions. By using Def file properly, the issue is solved.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand point 10? As 11 is "rename the file to .xll", which doesn't seem very confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I do not understand point 10. I corrected the question. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the compiler can produce a `.def` file for a .dll, but (I'm guessing) the reason this is not used here is that you want to have control as to what the names and placement of the symbols are - in particular, since the .dll uses __stdcall, not _cdecl type calling convention.

Here's a page that describes some of the particularities with gcc/mingw and DLL's, including how to use your own .def file:

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

In particular, the `dlltool`:

```
dlltool -U -d testdll.def -l libtestdll.a
```

Comment: In case someone incurr the same problem, the issue was definitely the naming convention of the exported functions. By using Def file properly, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your heart set on codeblocks & mingw, then you won't find https://xll.codeplex.com useful. It requires Microsoft's free version of Visual Studio.

If you need to build an xll to solve a problem, it might help you with that.